# Unable to stop Rollup records through DataLoader

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I unable to stop Rollup records through data loader.
I have trigger on lead object that fires an action at the time of records inserted.but due to error in data segment it is not executed. 
Please let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: laxmi, what do you mean by "**Stop Rollup records**"? can you please explain your problem a little more.

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Can you please share